# firebase.messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(*) 'handler' expected a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

Whenever I hot reload my app or an unhandled exception gets thrown and crashes my React Native App, this error message pops up. My index.js has

```
firebase.messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few reasons for that. It might be possible that `JSON.stringify(remoteMessage)` is getting crashed and since you have not added catch in your promise chain you are getting the unhandled exception.
Could you modify your code to below:

```js
firebase.messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
}).catch(e => {console.log(e)});
```

And then analyze the crash stack

Comment: Adding a .catch there throws a type error

Comment: Have you imported firebase/messaging?
Like import "firebase/messaging"

Comment: Yes, the app runs fine and sends notifications but anytime I force save this error happens